# winrt linear partitioning in listview

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

I want to create a grouped ListView with linear partitioning. The ListView has photos and it should look like this:
http://www.chromatic.io/FQrLQsb

There are easy ways for Android and Javascript but I use Winrt with Xaml and C#.

Thanx

UPDATE:
Now I have the following.
MyGridView:

```
public class MyGridView : GridView
{

    public MyGridView()
    {
    }
    protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyObject element, object item)
    {
        try
        {
            dynamic gridItem = item;

            var typeItem = item as FileThumb;
            if (typeItem != null)
            {
                var heightPecentage = (100.0 / typeItem.Height);
                var itemWidth = typeItem.Width * heightPecentage;
                var columnSpan = Convert.ToInt32(itemWidth / 10.0);

                if (gridItem != null)
                {
                    element.SetValue(VariableSizedWrapGrid.ItemWidthProperty, itemWidth);
                    element.SetValue(VariableSizedWrapGrid.ColumnSpanProperty, columnSpan);
                    element.SetValue(VariableSizedWrapGrid.RowSpanProperty, 1);
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            element.SetValue(VariableSizedWrapGrid.ItemWidthProperty, 100);
            element.SetValue(VariableSizedWrapGrid.ColumnSpanProperty, 1);
            element.SetValue(VariableSizedWrapGrid.RowSpanProperty, 1);
        }
        finally
        {
            base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);
        }
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <converter:ThumbnailToImageConverter x:Key="ThumbnailToImageConverter" />
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <local:MyGridView x:Name="myList">
        <local:MyGridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VariableSizedWrapGrid ItemWidth="10"  Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </local:MyGridView.ItemsPanel>
        <local:MyGridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Height="100">
                    <Image Stretch="Uniform" Source="{Binding thumb, Converter={StaticResource ThumbnailToImageConverter}}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </local:MyGridView.ItemTemplate>
    </local:MyGridView>
</Grid>
```

and the MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
    }

    private async void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<FileThumb> thumbs = new List<FileThumb>();
        try
        {
            StorageFolder pictureFolders = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFolderAsync("testbilder");
            try
            {
                var photoFiles = await pictureFolders.GetFilesAsync();

                foreach (StorageFile file in photoFiles)
                {
                    var thumbn = await file.GetScaledImageAsThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode.SingleItem);
                    thumbs.Add(new FileThumb() { thumb = thumbn, Height = thumbn.OriginalHeight/2, Width = thumbn.OriginalWidth/2, maxWidth = myList.ActualWidth });
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        myList.ItemsSource = thumbs;
    }
}

public class FileThumb
{
    public StorageItemThumbnail thumb { get; set; }
    public uint Height { get; set; }
    public uint Width { get; set; }
    public double maxWidth { get; set; }
}
```

the output looks like [this](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=FFD17EE5FCC8F04F!162454&authkey=!AMfeDdXIkQN-sbM&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng)

my problem is, that i want to fill the whole width of the screen. But I have no idea how to do it. the height could be variable.

Comment: Have you tried anything? As it sits, it seems you're basically just sharing your requirements. You can definitely do what you're after, but SO isn't a free code farm.

Comment: at the moment I didn't try anything because I don't have any idea how to do.So I don'twant a finished code. I want some ideas if someone had done something like this and can give me the first push

Comment: Look into [VariableSizeWrapGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227651.aspx) control. Jerry Nixon has a good [article](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/08/windows-8-beauty-tip-using.html) on it that might help you out.

Comment: thanx for that. That looks like a good starting point

Comment: please look at the update